# Show image in TImage dynamically (at run time) without opendialog in c++ builder xe8

Tags: android, c++, c++builder

I want to show image (png,jpg etc) in dynamically created (as per requirement and fully through coding) TImage component, at runtime in C++ builder xe8 (not delphi). But I dont want to use opendialogbox (suggested in many web sites). I want to run this app on my android device. I tried to use LoadFromFile(), it crashes the app on android, but when I run this on windows, its running smoothly. I am just a beginner to c++ builder. So guys pls help. Thanx in advance for any kind of help.Here is what I did.

```
void __fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
{
TImage* img = new TImage(this);
img->Parent = this;
img->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("D:\\res\\profile.png");
}
```

Comment: You don't need an OpenDialog just to open a file.  All the OpenDialog provides is a way for the user to select a path + filename, nothing more. If you already know the path + filename that you want to open, then just open it. If your code is crashing, you are likely doing something wrong. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see what is the error?

If you run the program with the provided by you code I assume the error would be that the file is not found, because there is no such directory "D:\" in android.

One way to set the path is to write a static path which points to your image. For example : "/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/MyImage.jpg";

The second way is to include the `<System.IOUtils.hpp>` header and to use some built-in functions like:

```
System::Ioutils::TPath::GetPicturesPath();
System::Ioutils::TPath::GetAlarmsPath();
```

You can check them out, they might be useful.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working, at least for me. I even copied the png file to the project folder, and used this code...    `img->Bitmap->LoadFromFile("profile.png");` whenever i run this on android, my app crashes, and its showing **Unfortunately "app_name" stopped**. @Zdravko Donev.

Comment: Run the application in debug mode, check what is the error and share it with us. You can debug the applications like a normal application on windows. The error will be shown on your screen, not on your phone.

Comment: Thank You very much sir, now it's working... actually it was all happening due to my misconception about **LoadFromFile()**. I though that, if I use this function it'll copy that image with it, and install along with the dex file.But when I mention the path according to the android os, its working fine. Thank You @Zdravko Donev.